# Undefined symbols "_sws_getContext" for architecture aarm64

Tags: c, ffmpeg, ninja, meson-build

I'm playing around with `scrcpy` source code (https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy).

I run my build of scrcpy with my Android phone and see that the AVFrame in this code (from `/app/src/screen.c`):

```
static bool
sc_screen_update_frame(struct sc_screen *screen) {
     av_frame_unref(screen->frame);
     sc_video_buffer_consume(&screen->vb, screen->frame);
     AVFrame *frame = screen->frame;
...
}
```

that the AVFrame that scrcpy gets from the device has the pixel format of `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P`.

I want to change this format to something more common like `AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA`. I found some tutorial online that suggested using `sws_getContext`.

So I add these lines to that `sc_screen_update_frame` function:

```
    AVFrame* converted = av_frame_alloc();
    converted->format = AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA;
    converted->width = frame->width;
    converted->height = frame->height;
    av_frame_get_buffer(converted, 0);
    struct SwsContext *img_convert_context = sws_getContext(frame->width,
                                                            frame->height,
                                                            (enum AVPixelFormat)frame->format,
                                                            converted->width,
                                                            converted->height,
                                                            (enum AVPixelFormat)converted->format,
                                                            SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    sws_scale(img_convert_context,
                frame->data,
                frame->linesize,
                0,
                converted->height,
                converted->data[0],
                converted->linesize);
```

And then I build scrcpy with "ninja -Cx" command but I got this error:

```
undef: _sws_getContext
undef: _sws_scale
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_sws_getContext", referenced from:
      _scrcpy in lto.o
  "_sws_scale", referenced from:
      _scrcpy in lto.o
```

I'm using a Macbook Pro with M1 CPU. Does that message mean that `sws_getContext` and `sws_scale` functions are not available for ARM CPUs? I appreciate any help, thank you!

Edit: I have included `#include <libswscale/swscale.h>` in `screen.c`